# Are there any R /Python packages to apply machine learning/deep learning models for longitudinal data?

Tags: r, machine-learning, mixed-model, python, panel-data

I am analysing a cohort study done on a certain disorder. It has around 80 baseline variables and a binary response variable indicating the presence or absence of the disease, collected at 4 time points. I can use generalised linear mixed models (logistic mixed effects models) to analyse the longitudinal data. However, I was wondering whether there are any open source R/Python packages available where I could apply machine learning techniques or deep learning techniques to model longitudinal data.